# Javascript Dropdown list from bootstrap click event listener behaving anomaly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, dropdown

I have a dropdown list (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button-dropdowns) with classname : seatsDropdownItems

I am for looping each element of seatsDropdownItems --> ["sections", "library", "odd", "even", "floor"] and attaching a click event listener.

What I want to achieve is that when a user click on one of the element, for e.g. even, it will do the necessary operations accordingly.

However it only works when I click on it once.

Test case 1: Clicked on "even" and do not care about this dropdown list anymore --> Working

Test case 2: Clicked on "even" but now wants to click on "odd" --> Not working. Issue: it does the operations / if block when it is even as well. It SHOULD not be executing if block for "even" value as the value now is changed to "odd".

I tried console logging the variable selection (which stores this/what is clicked element) and it shows me odd only but when I console log in the if blocks for different values (odd, even, etc), it is indeed executing "even".

```js
var selection;
for (let i = 0; i < seatsDropdownItems.length; i++) {
  seatsDropdownItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    selection = this.id;
    var dropDownBtnSeats = document.getElementById('dropdownMenuButton');
    dropDownBtnSeats.innerText = selection + " seats";
    console.log(selection);
    if (selection == "Odd" || selection == "Even") {
      fetchData('GET', libraryHost + "/get_seats/", )
        .then(data => {
          msg.innerHTML = text;
          msg.innerHTML += "you are blocking all the " + selection + " seats! Press confirm to continue.";
          msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-block");
          confirmBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-none");
            loading.setAttribute("class", "row d-block");
            var oddReservations = [];
            var evenReservations = [];
            var seats = data.seats;
            for (seat of seats) {
              if (seat.id % 2 == 0) {
                var evenReservationJSON = {
                  "student_id": user.user_id,
                  "library_id": seat.library_id,
                  "seat_id": seat.id,
                  "floor": seat.floor,
                  "section": seat.section,
                  "start": isoDTFrom,
                  "end": isoDTTo
                };
                evenReservations.push(evenReservationJSON);
              } else {
                var oddReservationJSON = {
                  "student_id": user.user_id,
                  "library_id": seat.library_id,
                  "seat_id": seat.id,
                  "floor": seat.floor,
                  "section": seat.section,
                  "start": isoDTFrom,
                  "end": isoDTTo
                };
                oddReservations.push(oddReservationJSON);
              }
            }
            if (selection == "Odd") {
              console.log('odd')
              create_reservation_bulk(oddReservations);
            } else {
              console.log('even')
              create_reservation_bulk(evenReservations);
            }
          });
        });
    } else {
      fetchData('GET', libraryHost + "/get_libraries/", )
        .then(data => {
          var libraries = data.libraries;
          msg.innerHTML = text;
          var specificationsDropdown = document.getElementById("specificationsDropdown");
          specificationsDropdown.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var string = msg.innerHTML;
            var count = (string.match(/continue/g) || []).length;
            if (count == 1) {
              msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-block");
            } else if (count >= 1) {
              var arr = string.split(",");
              msg.innerHTML = arr[0] + ", ";
              var arr1 = string.split(".");
              msg.innerHTML += arr1[1] + ".";
              msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-block");
            } else {
              msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-none");
            }
          });
          var html_str = `<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-block " type="button" id="dropdownMenuButtonLib" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            Choose Library
                                            </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">`;
          for (var library of libraries) {
            html_str += `<button class = "dropdown-item libraries" id = "${library.id}" value = "${library.name}">${library.name}</button>`;
          }
          html_str += `</div>`;
          specificationsDropdown.innerHTML = html_str;
          var librariesDropdownItems = document.getElementsByClassName("libraries");
          for (let j = 0; j < librariesDropdownItems.length; j++) {
            librariesDropdownItems[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
              library_id = this.id;
              var dropDownBtnLib = document.getElementById('dropdownMenuButtonLib');
              dropDownBtnLib.innerText = this.value;
              library = this.value;
              if (selection == "Floor" || selection == "Section") {
                var specificationsDropdown2 = document.getElementById("specificationsDropdown2");
                msg.innerHTML = text;
                specificationsDropdown2.addEventListener("click", function() {
                  var string = msg.innerHTML;
                  var count = (string.match(/continue/g) || []).length;
                  if (count == 1) {
                    msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-block");
                  } else if (count >= 1) {
                    var arr = string.split(",");
                    msg.innerHTML = arr[0] + ", ";
                    var arr1 = string.split(".");
                    msg.innerHTML += arr1[1] + ".";
                    msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-block");
                  } else {
                    msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-none");
                  }
                });
                var html_str2 = `<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButtonFloor" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                        Choose Floor
                                                        </button>
                                                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">`;
                for (let el of libraries) {
                  if (el.id == library_id) {
                    var numOfFloors = el.floors;
                  }
                }
                for (let k = 2; k < numOfFloors + 2; k++) {
                  html_str2 += `<button class = "dropdown-item floors" id = "${k}" value = "${k}">${k}</button>`;
                }
                html_str2 += `</div>`;
                specificationsDropdown2.innerHTML = html_str2;
                var floorsDropdownItems = document.getElementsByClassName("floors");
                for (let a = 0; a < floorsDropdownItems.length; a++) {
                  floorsDropdownItems[a].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    floor = this.id;
                    var dropDownBtnFloor = document.getElementById('dropdownMenuButtonFloor');
                    dropDownBtnFloor.innerText = "Floor " + this.id;
                    if (selection == "Section") {
                      console.log("yes");
                      //selection = "";
                      var specificationsDropdown3 = document.getElementById("specificationsDropdown3");
                      msg.innerHTML = text;
                      specificationsDropdown3.addEventListener("click", function() {
                        var string = msg.innerHTML;
                        var count = (string.match(/continue/g) || []).length;
                        if (count == 1) {
                          msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-block");
                        } else if (count >= 1) {
                          var arr = string.split(",");
                          msg.innerHTML = arr[0] + ", ";
                          var arr1 = string.split(".");
                          msg.innerHTML += arr1[1] + ".";
                          msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-block");
                        } else {
                          msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-none");
                        }
                      });
                      var html_str3 = `<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButtonSec" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                                        Choose Section
                                                                        </button>
                                                                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">`;
                      postData = {
                        "library_id": library_id,
                        "floor": floor
                      }
                      fetchData('GET', libraryHost + "/get_sections_by_library_floor/", postData)
                        .then(data => {
                          var sectionsArr = data.sections;
                          for (let section of sectionsArr) {
                            html_str3 += `<button class = "dropdown-item sections" id = "${section.section}" value = "${section.venue}">${section.venue}</button>`;
                          }
                          html_str3 += `</div>`;
                          specificationsDropdown3.innerHTML = html_str3;
                          var sectionsDropdownItems = document.getElementsByClassName("sections");
                          for (let a = 0; a < sectionsDropdownItems.length; a++) {
                            sectionsDropdownItems[a].addEventListener('click', function() {
                              section_id = this.id;
                              section = this.value;
                              var dropDownBtnSec = document.getElementById('dropdownMenuButtonSec');
                              dropDownBtnSec.innerText = this.value;
                              msg.innerHTML += "you are blocking section " + section + " of floor " + floor + " of " + library + "! Press confirm to continue.";
                              msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-block");
                              confirmBtn.setAttribute("class", "row justify-content-center d-block");
                              confirmBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
                                msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-none");
                                loading.setAttribute("class", "row d-block");
                                specificationsDropdown.innerHTML = "";
                                specificationsDropdown2.innerHTML = "";
                                specificationsDropdown3.innerHTML = "";
                                postData = {
                                  "library_id": library_id,
                                  "floor": floor,
                                  "section": section_id
                                }
                                fetchData('GET', libraryHost + "/get_seats_by_library_floor_section/", postData)
                                  .then(data => {
                                    var sectionReservations = [];
                                    var seats = data.seats;
                                    for (seat of seats) {
                                      var sectionReservationJSON = {
                                        "student_id": user.user_id,
                                        "library_id": seat.library_id,
                                        "seat_id": seat.id,
                                        "floor": seat.floor,
                                        "section": seat.section,
                                        "start": isoDTFrom,
                                        "end": isoDTTo
                                      };
                                      sectionReservations.push(sectionReservationJSON);
                                    }
                                    console.log("section");
                                    create_reservation_bulk(sectionReservations);
                                  });
                              });
                            });
                          }
                        });
                    } else {
                      //selection = "";
                      msg.innerHTML += "you are blocking floor " + floor + " of " + library + "! Press confirm to continue.";
                      msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-block");
                      confirmBtn.setAttribute("class", "row justify-content-center d-block")
                      confirmBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
                        msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-none");
                        loading.setAttribute("class", "row d-block");
                        specificationsDropdown.innerHTML = "";
                        specificationsDropdown2.innerHTML = "";
                        postData = {
                          "library_id": library_id,
                          "floor": floor
                        }
                        fetchData('GET', libraryHost + "/get_seats_by_library_floor/", postData)
                          .then(data => {
                            var floorReservations = [];
                            var seats = data.seats;
                            for (seat of seats) {
                              var floorReservationJSON = {
                                "student_id": user.user_id,
                                "library_id": seat.library_id,
                                "seat_id": seat.id,
                                "floor": seat.floor,
                                "section": seat.section,
                                "start": isoDTFrom,
                                "end": isoDTTo
                              };
                              floorReservations.push(floorReservationJSON);
                            }
                            console.log('floor')
                            create_reservation_bulk(floorReservations);
                          });
                      });
                    }
                  });
                }
              } else {
                //selection = "";
                for (let j = 0; j < librariesDropdownItems.length; j++) {
                  librariesDropdownItems[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    msg.innerHTML += "you are blocking " + library + "! Press confirm to continue.";
                    msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-block");
                    confirmBtn.setAttribute("class", "row justify-content-center d-block");
                    confirmBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
                      msg.setAttribute("class", "card-text d-none");
                      loading.setAttribute("class", "row d-block");
                      specificationsDropdown.innerHTML = "";
                      postData = {
                        "library_id": library_id,
                      }
                      fetchData('GET', libraryHost + "/get_seats_by_library/", postData)
                        .then(data => {
                          var libraryReservations = [];
                          var seats = data.seats;
                          for (seat of seats) {
                            var libraryReservationJSON = {
                              "student_id": user.user_id,
                              "library_id": seat.library_id,
                              "seat_id": seat.id,
                              "floor": seat.floor,
                              "section": seat.section,
                              "start": isoDTFrom,
                              "end": isoDTTo
                            };
                            libraryReservations.push(libraryReservationJSON);
                          }
                          console.log('odd')
                          create_reservation_bulk(libraryReservations);
                        });
                    });
                  });
                }
              }
            });
          }
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and frameworks in a [mcve]

Comment: Your code is unreadable and unmaintainable.